# SD memory card recovery - CRC error

Tags: sd-card, file-recovery

I need to recover important photos from an SD card.

I was taking pictures with a nikon D90. When I went to put the card into a computer (tried two machines), it did not recognize the card. The drive shows up, but when I click on the DCIM folder, it comes up with a CRC error, and of course, the files are not viewable.

When I put the card back into the D90 camera, however, I can view them.

I tried CHKDSK but it said it cannot do RAW file systems. I am not sure what the original file system was on the card, because I only got to use it once after buying the camera with the SD card in it before the error arose.

I am looking for software to:

> 1. create an image of the drive before the situation gets any worse
> 2. attempt recovery of the drive, if possible, without writing to the actual drive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you connect through USB to the camera can't you access the card and copy the data?

Comment: test disk, photorec and ZAR recovery didn't work

Answer (score 2):

Since you **can** view the images in the D90, why not transfer them directly from the camera to PC by USB cable? Once the files are saved, you can format the card in the camera, which creates directories, or scrap it.

Directions for file transfer are on p. 148 of the user manual, available at http://cdn-10.nikon-cdn.com/pdf/manuals/kie88335f7869dfuejdl=-cww2/D90_en.pdf.

If your computer OS causes transfer issue, see http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-hardware/cannot-import-photos-from-camerenikon-d90-after/b88137fd-d611-47da-b114-860a23efbf94 for *Windows 8*, http://www.dpreview.com/forums/thread/2945968 for *Linux* or other sites.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you two alternatives to try.

1. There are Nikon Camera drivers/software available. Please check that if any installation/update is needed or not in your PC.
2. Try using a branded new USB card reader to transfer your photos.